# Cannot install 3rd party in VS code, pip

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am trying to install both pip

```
pip install PyAutoGUI
pip install python-telegram-bot
```

but both also show the similar error message.

[image]

it stated about WinError 2.

My python version is Python 3.10.7

I've directed the right path in System Environment Variable to python.exe.

Anyone has experienced this error?

Comment: Please [don't post code/errors/data as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: Ok. Thanks for helping me edit the question. Will take note on that

Answer (score 0):

> pip install PyAutoGUI
>
> pip install python-telegram-bot

This install command works on my vscode.

I guess you have an out of date version of setuptools. Try the following codes to update your setuptools and reinstall the two packages:

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

Comment: Same error message.

I managed to install python telegram bot 

'pip install python-telegram-bot==20.0a4'

which was a pre-release version. But cant find it for pyautogui

Comment: Can other packages be installed? I think this is more like a problem with the package instead of vscode. It is more appropriate to ask their developers in github.

Comment: I've installed Django and few other packages before but somehow the pyautogui just cant seemed to go through... unless there's other newer version or maybe other alternative

Comment: You can ask the developer of this package [here](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

rollback pip to an older version:

python -m pip install pip==18.1
install desired module:

pip install pyautogui
update pip:

python -m pip install --upgrade pip
P.S. this solution works for other modules too.

This was answered by Michael Chon in other post.

Comment: Please add a link to where you obtained this solution. You can [edit] this answer.